# How to get all href values from a list with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, href

I want to retrieve all URIs from the `href` attributes with JQuery. How could I do that?

Here an example of the HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
    <li class="active"><a href="www.myweb.com/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li> 
    <li><a href="www.myweb.com/findyourcity">Find Your City</a></li> 
    <li><a href="www.myweb.com/howitwork">How It Works</a></li> 
    <li><a href="www.myweb.com/faq">FAQ</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Please include an actual question. Which programming language? What are you trying to do here? You've included a MVC tag, but no further explanation to what you mean by that

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="www.myweb.com/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="www.myweb.com/findyourcity">Find Your City</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="www.myweb.com/howitwork">How It Works</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="www.myweb.com/faq">FAQ</a></li>
                                </ul>

Comment: I want to get all href values in jquery

Comment: how to get href values in jquery

Comment: Check this dude: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57285175/9066218

Answer (score 14):

To get a single attribute value you use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like this:

```
$('selector').attr('href');
```

However that will only give you the attribute value for the *first* item found. To get multiple values, use [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
$('selector').map( function() {
    return $(this).attr('href');
}).get();
```

In your case the selector could be `navbar-nav a` as you seem to want all the links in your navbar, which makes your code this:

```
var allLinks = $('.navbar-nav a').map( function() {
    return $(this).attr('href');
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arrayVariable = [ ];
$(".nav li").each(function (i){
    arrayVariable[i]=$(this).find("a").attr('href');
});

$("#zz").html(arrayVariable + "");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
    <li class="active">
      <a href="www.myweb.com/home">Home</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <a href="www.myweb.com/findyourcity">Find Your City</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <a href="www.myweb.com/howitwork">How It Works</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <a href="www.myweb.com/faq">FAQ</a>
    </li> 
</ul>
<div id="zz"></div>
```